# Can I simulate a PUT or a DELETE request using a POST request with Sinatra?

Tags: html, ruby, http, rest, sinatra

Some web browsers can't make PUT or DELETE requests, but I need to make those to my REST service written in Ruby using Sinatra. Is it possible to make Sinatra interpret a POST request as a PUT or DELETE request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read [the document](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html) and find the description of `method_override`. The mechanism is identical as Rails. If your browser doesn't support `PUT` & `DELETE`, just send a extra parameter named `_method` with value `PUT` or `DELETE`.

Notice that in **Modular** application (your class inherits `Sinatra::Base`), `method_override` is disabled by default. You need to enable it manually.

Comment: I put `enable :method_override` in my `Sinatra::Base` subclass and it works great. :)

Answer (score 3):

All current web browsers support PUT and DELETE in XMLHttpRequest. Also, as far as I know, no browser supports them in HTML forms, mainly because it hasn't been specified yet what they'd do precisely.